# Inkscape: How to change starting node?

Tags: svg, inkscape

I am using inkscape to create svg. Later I am going animate drawing that svg path in a website using [vivus.js](http://maxwellito.github.io/vivus/).
Problem is I have no control over the starting node of the path in inkscape. To make myself clear, suppose I want to animate drawing of the following characte's svg path created in inkscape:

[image: svg character]

In inkscape the starting node of the path is shown as below:

[image: starting node]

So animation starts drawing from this node which does not look normal since normally you don't start writing "a" from that point. That's why I'd like to change the starting node to the following:

[image: new starting node]

I am looking for coding solution to change starting and ending nodes.

Comment: I doubt there is any internal way of doing this in Inkscape.  You just have to open up the SVG code and edit the `d` attribute.

Comment: Then you'll have to re-index all the nodes which seems next to impossible for some paths.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "re-index" all the nodes.  It's mostly just cut and paste, since I'm fairly certain Inkscape uses absolute coordinates for its paths.  You would only have to clean up the starting/ending points.  Post the code & I'll show how to re-write it.  But I'm not an Inkscape expert.  If you want a software solution, try on [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) -- as the close-voters suggested, Stack Overflow is for people working with the SVG code, not for tips on using graphics software.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. As a matter of fact I am a coder and looking for coding solution. I will edit my question. Here is a sample path: <path style="fill:#000000;" d="M665.54652,160.9067c-1.95059-1.71264-3.54652-3.73375-3.54652-4.49136,0-1.68732,6.19761-14.41534,7.01921-14.41534,0.32448,0,2.31185,1.57719,4.41639,3.50488,3.50859,3.21374,3.7815,3.83989,3.28546,7.53809-0.61283,4.56897-2.79716,8.39221-5.67454,9.93214-1.59793,0.85518-2.599,0.4787-5.5-2.06841z"/>

Comment: @R.B.: Did you ever get this working? :)

Comment: @Marc I managed to change the order in inkscape.

Comment: @R.B.:  Oh ok :) ... and how did that work?^^ ... is there any good resource on this? It would be nice if you could answer this question if you have the time so people could find it :-)

Comment: @Marc Dear Marc, I sure will in a few days.

Comment: @R.B.: Hi :) I would still like to know how I can accomplish this ;) Thank you.

Comment: @Gazoris I just came across the same problem. Can you guide us on how you did this? Any help is greatly appreciated - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kkGwpq?editors=1100

Answer (score 7):

One way to do this in Inkscape is to select the node that you want to be the starting node, break the path at this node, and then re-join the path. It's a little hacky, but it works. :)

Comment: This didn't change the ordering when I tried. It simply put a relative `m 0 0` command into the SVG file to break the line.